# Installation of capybara-webkit gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara-webkit

I have following errors when I try to install capybara-webkit gem.

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/s/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
    cd src/ && /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake /home/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7- 
    p371@/gems/capybara-webkit-0.14.1/src/webkit_server.pro -spec 
   /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o Makefile.webkit_server
   cd src/ && make -f Makefile.webkit_server 
   make[1]: Entering directory `/home/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@/gems/capybara-     webkit-0.14.1/src'

   g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WEBKIT_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB - DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. - I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui - I/usr/include/qt4/QtWebKit -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. -o EnableLogging.o EnableLogging.cpp
   g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WEBKIT_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -  DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. - I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui - I/usr/include/qt4/QtWebKit -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. -o Authenticate.o Authenticate.cpp
 In file included from Authenticate.cpp:2:0:
 WebPage.h:46:17: error: incomplete type ‘QNetworkReply’ used in nested name specifier   
 WebPage.h:46:17: error: incomplete type ‘QNetworkReply’ used in nested name specifier
 WebPage.h:46:45: error: template argument 1 is invalid
 make[1]: *** [Authenticate.o] Error 1
 make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/capybara-  webkit-0.14.1/src'
 make: *** [sub-src-webkit_server-pro-make_default-ordered] Error 2
 Command 'make' failed
```

I use Ubuntu and I have installed libqt4-dev and g++. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Report a bug to the vendor who is responsible for this package, they have a bug in their software.